# Under what conditions is it valid to use Field injection instead of Constructor injection?

Tags: gwt, dependency-injection, dependencies, guice

I am using GUICE as a Dependency injection container. If I have an option to go for either Constructor injection or Field injection, I believe that I should always prefer Constructor injection over field injection. Is my understanding correct?

Are there any valid use cases where Field injection would make more sense than Constructor injection?

Comment: I think this is a matter of style and cannot be answered with true/false on SO. I would ask the other way around: why care about constructor/setter injection unless you write code that must be used without DI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're correct. Try to avoid field injection when possible.

The most important thing, I believe, is when you use constructor injection, you can be absolutely sure that your objects will never be in inconsistent state, because you cannot create such object without creating its dependencies first. Also dependencies declared in constructor present clear contract for your class - you can easily see what that class depends on. This is not always true with field injection.

Moreover, you can use such objects without DI frameworks, for example, in unit tests. With field injection, on the contrary (especially when fields are private) you can't use your classes outside of DI container without excessive hassle. Your fields also can't be `final` if you employ field injection and want portability, and that's bad because you should try to make objects as immutable as possible.

Field injections are almost never needed. They are only good for optional dependencies (and even for these I suggest using method injection instead) or for special "aspect"-like dependencies, for example, loggers.

Another highly arguable use case is when you need create a class which has several superclasses, each having dependencies. With constructor injection you will have to pass all dependencies for all your superclasses through all constructors up to the top. This may be inconvenient, and field injection solves this. But this is a very rare use case (I've only encountered it in my practice once), and I personally think that passing dependencies through multiple constructors is not that bad.

Comment: The one place I've used field injection to good effect is when you have a base class that needs dependencies, but the subclasses don't. If you strictly use ctor injection, then you wind up with lots of parameters that have to just get passed through to the super() call. And when your base class needs another parameter, you have to go update all your subclasses.

Comment: @jgindin, yes, that's a part of what I meant in the last paragraph. But I'd argue that method injections are exactly as good as field injections for that, but are also much more flexible.

Comment: With frameworks with support for @PostConstruct I feel as though field injection vs constructor injection becomes a matter of style.  Particularly if you are writing serializable services, which don't benefit from the use of final fields as much.  I tend to use both depending on the circumstances, since I do find field injection to read a little better